# Domestic Travel to USVI with expired L1B

Tags: usa, visa, l1-visa

trying to figure out how a travel to the USVI could turn out in my situation: I have an expired L1B Visa (expired stamp), and I am legally allowed to stay in the US for a few more months, as I have filed a visa extension timely (which allows me to stay in the US until my visa is extended).
Can I travel safely to the USVI under these circumstances?
I would expect that domestic flights are fine, however it seems like I am crossing again the CBP, so I am wondering if there are any issues with getting outside US mainland.
Thanks advance !

Comment: When did your I-94 expire?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is fine for you to travel to the US Virgin Islands, as it is within the US immigration system. If you encounter the CBP, you just need to show them that you are staying in the US legally, which you can with your Extension of Stay application receipt (which you should bring with you).